# SignalR for Swift iOS native app

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, swift, signalr

i've read this article but it uses xamarin

```
http://components.xamarin.com/view/signalr
```

So anyone have tried and tested a SWIFT library for build a signalr (versione 2.x) ios native app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a work on-going:
https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR

I wish Microsoft can build an official ios client for SignalR

Answer (score 0):

No, because Xamarin is not capable of building a [static] library that can be consumed by a Swift app.